# Java thread-safety: enum and static methods

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Am I righ that the method sortList (see pseudo-code below) is thread-safe?

My understanding that "yes", since there are no any variables here, but I have to be sure. The pseudo-code:

```
//This method should be thread-safe
public static void sortList (List<MyObject> list, SortType sortType) {
  Collections.sort(list, sortType.getComparator());
}

//Defines type of sorting
public static enum SortType {
  BY_FIELD_1 (new ComparatorByField1()),
  BY_FIELD_2 (new ComparatorByField2()),
  ...
  BY_FIELD_N (new ComparatorByFieldN());

  private comparator;
  private SortType (Comparator comparator) {
    this.comparator = comparator;
  }

  public getComparator () {
    return comparator;
  }

  //Method getFieldX in pseudo-code bellow returns a number
  private static class ComparatorByField1 implements Comparator<MyObject> {
    public int compare (MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return (int) (o1.getField1() - o2.getField1());
    }
  }
  ...

  private static class ComparatorByFieldN implements Comparator<MyObject> {
    public int compare (MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return (int) (o1.getFieldN() - o2.getFieldN();
    }
  }
...
}
```

Comment: this may help as starting point:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have thread-safety issues, if you have 2 or more threads accessing the **same** data at "the same time".

Your methods are **only** manipulating their parameters. This means that no matter how often or how many threads are calling those methods, you shouldn't run into problems.

Unless, of course, you would be calling these methods on the **same** objects.

So, what we see so far is thread-safe.

But if you your real code would do something like

```
List<YourObject> someObjects = ...
sortList(someObjects);
sortList(someObjects);
```

(basically sorting the same array twice, possible at the same time) ... that would not be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. I see were problem may be. I will avoid modifications of already processed lists.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that method is not thread safe. You were on a right path by counting number of variables involved in a call, but you forgot to include function arguments in count.

Problem with sortList method is that `mylist` argument is possibly shared between threads and imagine what would happen if two threads try to sort list in opposite directions at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. I will prevent modification of  arguments passed to sortLists.